# How to count a string in all columns for only rows that contain a certain value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

VBA newbie here and I've looked hard to find macros that I can tweak and combine to get this done but have not been able to do so.

I've pasted some of my sample data at the end of this post. I would like to go through column 1 (ID_Num) and find all rows with the same ID_Num (they should be next to each other in the column since the sheet is sorted by ID_Num). Then put down a count of 1 for each customer when the string "A", "B" or "C" is found under the customer column for each block of rows with identical ID_Nums. The count should not be greater than 1 i.e if the string "A" or "B" or "C" is present in the range, then a 1 is registered, otherwise 0 is registered. The other possibilities are "D" or blanks.

I would like to have only one row per ID_Num after this step.

Finally, I'd like to add up these 1s and 0s for each ID_Num

I have attached an example of the data I have and where I want to end up.

Original data sample

> ID_Num |  Customer 1  Customer 2  Customer 3  Customer 4  Customer 5
>
> aaa    | A A   D   B   D
>
> aaa    | B D   D   B   A
>
> aaa    | D D   D   A   B
>
> bbb    | C A   D   D   C
>
> ccc    | D A   A   A   D
>
> ccc    | A C   B D D
>
> ddd    | D D   D   D   D

Step One

> ID_Num   | Customer 1     Customer 2      Customer 3      Customer 4   Customer 5
>
> aaa    | 1 1   0   1   1
>
> bbb    | 1 1   0   0   1
>
> ccc    | 1 1   1   1   0
>
> ddd    | 0 0   0   0   0

Step Two

> ID_Num | Final Count
>
> aaa    | 4
>   bbb    | 3
>   ccc    | 4
>   ddd    | 0

There are 100 customer columns.

Sorry about the formatting. I have included a link to an image that shows the same information. The website won't allow me upload the image

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPeHw.png)

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done with formulas, there is no real need to use VBA that I can see.  Why do you want to use VBA?

Comment: I should have mentioned that using VBA was not a requirement. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Sheet1 contain the initial Data, in Sheet2 column A is ID_Num and Row1 is the customers, in B2 write:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!B:B,"A")>0,COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!B:B,"B")>0,COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!B:B,"C")>0),1,0)
```

and drag it in the same row till the last customer and down till last ID_Num it will change automatically and you will have the Table in Step One
When finish you can create after the last column Final Count and use:

`=Sum(B2:ZZ2)`
replace ZZ2 by the last customer column and drag it down

If You want Step Two alone Copy the ID_Num column and paste it to a new sheet and copy the column of Final Count use paste special Values in the new sheet near the column of ID_Num

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much, Sam!